# Клиент-серверная валидация на ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, валидация

В своём проекте я использую ненавязчивую валидацию с добавлением атрибутов к свойствам класса модели.
Имеется класс:

```
public class Person
{
//some properties
[RegularExpression("[a-zA-ZА-Яа-я]*")]
public int LAST_NAME {get; set;}
}
```

Т.е. я предполагаю, что при валидации на клиентской стороне будет допускаться ввод только русских и английских символов (заглавных и строчных).
Если вводить фамилию на английской раскладке, то всё работает, однако валидация русских букв не проходит.
 При этом **ValidationMessageFor-helper** возвращает вот такое сообщение:

```
"The field LAST_NAME must match the regular expression '[à-ÿÀ-ß]*'."
```

Насколько я понимаю, проблема кроется в культуре. Если кто-либо сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите решение. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема - не в культуре, а в кодировке. Проверьте следующие места:

1. кодировку .cs-файла и совпадает ли она с ожидаемой компилятором. Для этого попробуйте в отладчике в окне Watches ("Контрольные значения") набрать `typeof(Person).GetProperty("LAST_NAME").GetCustomAttributes()` и посмотрите что туда записалось.
2. кодировку исходников веб-страницы и понимает ли ее веб-сервер. Напрямую она на проблему не влияет - но ее проверка позволит избежать двойной (замаскированной) ошибки. Напишите где-нибудь на странице что-то вроде `@{ var q = "Привет, мир!"; }` и посмотрите в отладчике чему равна эта переменная.
3. кодировку веб-страницы и понимает ли ее браузер. У вас на странице вообще русские буквы есть?

Comment: В столбце Value окна "Watch" получаю "This expression causes side effects and will not be evaluated". Русские буквы присутствуют. Кодировка страницы на клиенте - UTF-8.

Comment: @klutch1991 там должна быть кнопка, которая запустит выражение вычисляться.

Comment: Выдаёт {object[0x00000000]}.

Comment: @klutch1991 не верю. Там должен быть массив из одного элемента.

Comment: но так и есть. Метод GetCustomAttributes(false) возвращает object[0x00000000].

Comment: @klutch1991 object[0x00000000] - это пустой массив

Comment: Получается, что атрибутов нет. Свойство CustomAttributes тоже пустое. Такое вообще может быть?

Comment: Павел, я дико извиняюсь. В процессе отладки закомментировал атрибут.

Comment: В свойстве Pattern лежат нечитаемые символы. Вместо русских букв - иероглифы.

Comment: @klutch1991 значит, у вас проблема номер 1. Сохраните файл с исходным кодом в кодировке UTF-8.

Comment: Павел, спасибо за помощь. Всё работает.